# SESSION or SQL?

Tags: php, sql, session, bigdata

I have been using a robot I've coded from quite a while now and it works pretty well.
It goes to a domain, parse the index, save all internal links in a session var (lets call it array1), then refresh itself, move the index to an other session var (array2) and deletes it from array1, parses the next page in array1, check if the new internal links it finds are already in either of the two arrays, if not it saves them in array1, and so on. It basically makes a list of all pages within a domain.

This bot has been crawling some pretty big websites (20k+ pages) and it did fine, it just took some time, but that does not bother me. Now I want it to crawl some even bigger websites (200k+ pages), and I would like to have your opinion on the best way to handle data.

Should I carry on with sessions ? I know sessions use disk space, and even though my raspberry pi is quite stable, is it gonna be able to handle 20Mb+ variables ?
Should I keep all URL's in a sql tables ? In which case how well can sql handle this amount of data?

Thank you.

(I have searched the web but nothing seems to be really close to what I'm experiencing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR**: I bet you will run into completely different issues (storage space, computational power, OS limitations) before running into MySQL specific limitations.

---

MySQL limits:

Per field by type (http://www.electrictoolbox.com/maximum-length-mysql-text-field-types/):

```
TINYTEXT     256 bytes   
TEXT         64kb
MEDIUMTEXT   16MB
LONGTEXT     4GB
```

Per table by platform (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html)

```
Win32         FAT/FAT32    2GB/4GB
Win32         NTFS         2TB (possibly larger)
Linux 2.2 x86              2GB (LFS: 4GB)
Linux 2.4+    ext3         4TB
Solaris 9/10               16TB
MacOS X       HFS+         2TB
NetWare       NSS          8TB
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, I knew about the size limits but i wasnt sure how well sql could handle it, and by that I mean could sql be insanely slow when returning 100MB result ? I got my answer now. Cheers !

Comment: http://tagide.com/blog/2012/08/how-to-handle-large-data-in-mysql/ post kinda shows that 100MB resultset is nothing out of ordinary.

Comment: This article is really helpful. I won't have as many issues as that guy had since I "just" need to select hundreds thousands or maybe few millions of rows, no more than that, and always need to select all of them. I should be fine, I'll try that later on tonight. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

For sure databases can handle much more data than sessions. They are designed for that. Some GB large databases are nothing exciting for MySQL, Postgresql or MS SQLserver.